# FindBugs is not able to start

Tags: findbugs

When i tried to start the findbugs tool using the command line, i got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.DetectorFactoryCollection.getCoreResource(DetectorFactoryCollection.java:360)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.SystemProperties.loadPropertiesFromConfigFile(SystemProperties.java:72)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.SystemProperties.<clinit>(SystemProperties.java:55)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.Project.<clinit>(Project.java:91)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugsCommandLine.<init>(FindBugsCommandLine.java:59)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugsCommandLine.<init>(FindBugsCommandLine.java:78)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.gui2.GUI2CommandLine.<init>(GUI2CommandLine.java:49)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.gui2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:47)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.LaunchAppropriateUI.launch(LaunchAppropriateUI.java:109)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.LaunchAppropriateUI.main(LaunchAppropriateUI.java:195)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load parent plugins [edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugins.webCloud] in order to load [edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugins.findbugsCommunalCloud]
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.PluginLoader.finishLazyInitialization(PluginLoader.java:265)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.PluginLoader.loadInitialPlugins(PluginLoader.java:1393)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.PluginLoader.<clinit>(PluginLoader.java:155)
    ... 12 more
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Download findbug archive with cloudplugin disabled from http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html

Also dont forget to set %FINDBUGS_HOME% env variable to point to findbugs dir.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the absolute path to the jar.

e.g.: C:\findbugs-2.0.3-rc2>java -jar ./lib/findbugs.jar